# Jquery ticker not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I don't know why I've had a few issues explaining this problem so I have created this image to show what I am trying to do.

[image: Issue]

I have a ticker and I'm simply trying to duplicate it below the existing one with a different list. the black tile bar just represents a break so don't worry about styling. I hope this is possible, if not I would also like to know why.

Many Many thanks, attached is a [JSfiddle](http://bit.ly/1F2n0pU) if it is possible to show a working example in the JSfiddle it would be even nicer :)

Comment: So you're trying to make another one of these with different information in it but it would do the same thing?

Comment: I'm just trying to get some assistance. I'm not trying to be a inconvenience. I dont want to be a pain. I just want to learn. I have tried deleting the others due to my poor english

Comment: you've asked the same question 6 times now. A simple google search will show that you can't have 2 tickers on the same page. Give it up!

Comment: Sorry I meant you're trying to get another ticker on the page with different information in it?

Comment: Well i appreciate your comment, there no where on google which says it cant. unless your redirected here. as much as i appreciated you 'answer' Rachel. you actually did not do what i was requesting, you changed the number of stocks in the list. when i responded to your initial comment you never got back to me.